# Correct command for running node.js project with pm2 in ApplicationStart hook

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I want to set up [ApplicationStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) hook for node.js project where pm2 is used as a process manager in aws ec2 server.

I checked some tutorials and the shell script for ApplicationStart hook contains commands for running the project by using:

- node/npm
- pm2

for example in [this](https://blog.devgenius.io/deploy-a-reactjs-application-to-aws-ec2-instance-using-aws-codepipeline-3df5e4157028) tutorial, the shell script contains:

```
npm start
pm2 start npm --name "covidapp" -- start
```

in [this](https://fidisys.com/blog/AWS-EC2-CI-CD/) tutorial, the shell script contains:

```
pm2 start npm --name "myApp"
node app.js > app.out.log 2> app.err.log < /dev/null &
```

Why we are running the project two times? Why we just don't use pm2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deployed several apps on EC2 using PM2 and in my experience there should be no need (or benefit) to use `node app.js`, `npm start` or similar.

As you are probably already guessing, the whole point of PM2 is to run the process(es).

My recommendation would be to create a PM2 ecosystem configuration with all needed configurations, number of processes, ENV vars etc. I personally prefer this way even when running only one single node application on the server.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

And start the process(es) using the configuration, eg.:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

I also recommend using PM2 startup generator to make sure PM2 is started on server reboot: `pm2 startup`

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Once you have the startup script generated. Start your processes using pm2 manually or by using a configuration file (see example above). Verify with `pm2 status` that all processes are running as expected and execute `pm2 save` to "snapshot" the current state. The saved state will now automatically respawn on reboot.